# How can I level up more slowly?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I have played Skyrim for 2 hours and I am already level 22! I cannot figure out why I level so quickly! I hit someone with my steel mace and my One Handed skill goes up by 2! I am even playing on Legendary difficulty!

Any hints on what could happening (I have no mods installed) and how I can stop levelling up so far? Also is there any way to decrease my level with console commands?

Comment: I'm not sure, so this is a comment (any answerer who actually knows can feel free to steal):  I believe the highest difficulty is WHY you're leveling faster than normal.  Enemies are much tougher on that difficulty, so anything you manage to do them, or even just with them around, should give lots more experience in that skill than you're used to on lesser difficulties.

Comment: @gatherer818 It shouldn't be the case according to [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45999/do-you-gain-more-experience-on-higher-difficulty-levels)

Comment: Nope, changing the difficulty didn't work. Do you know any mods that make skyrim harder?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau heh, figures I'm wrong, that's why I posted as comment.  LBMF_1, don't worry too much, leveling up too fast will make the game harder all on its own.  Bad guys scale to level for a good while, so if your weapons and armor don't keep up because you're leveling too fast, the game will get harder until your gear catches up.  Have fun!

Comment: The game is waaayyy too easy! And yes, I did level that fast. I am only at Bleak falls barrow, without doing side quests! But, I just added more levels to my character and now she levels slower. Thanks!

Comment: Legendary? Way to easy? You trolling?

Comment: No. I do not know why, but every hit or block that I have puts me up a couple levels in that skill. Then, when I face a leveled enemy, I get wrecked.

Comment: That sounds bugged. Esp on legendary. When I played on the mastery level I had a lot of difficulties, and certainly didn't level that fast. Did you install any mods before?

Comment: Yeah, a while ago I had a fast leveling mod, and I deleted it. When I installed Dawnguard,I started leveling faster.

Comment: Aha that explains. Did you start a new game? You cannot really remove mods from a game in progress. (Some scripts get saved in the save file or somethin).

Comment: Ok. If I start a new game, will I not level up fast? I am planning on doing a you die, your games over playthrough. Will this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If playing on the PC, the mod, [**SkyTweak**](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/33395/?) can allow you to decrease (or increase) your experience gain rate.

For example, in this screenshot of the SkyTweak settings here, I am setting the One-Handed skill experience gain rate to half of what it is originally:

[image]

You might also want to see [How to make Skyrim more challenging at higher character levels?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/63622/4797)

Answer (score 3):

In Skyrim, character progression is solely based on levelling skills. Having said that, there are not many ways you can do to prevent levelling "too fast". However, doing the following should slow your progress:

1. Do not use Warrior, Mage, or Thief standing stone. These will increase the experience you gain from doing relevant thing. For example, if you have Warrior standing stone activated, you will level all your melee combat skill faster when performing those actions.
2. Do not pay NPC and learn any skills from them.
3. This might not be a real solution, but stick to one particular combat strategy will also help a little bit. For example, if you've been doing two-handed weapon so far, stick with it. Skills tend to level faster at low level, so by **NOT** performing those actions will prevent you from levelling fast.
4. **(Warning: You will lose all Stolen items doing this so be sure to be clean)**

   Goto Jail and serve your time.
   To do this, you need to whack a guard, or steal something to the point where you get the option to goto jail. Accept, and *do your time* by sleeping in the provided bed. This resets all skills progress. **(NOT THE LEVEL, JUST THE PROGRESS TO THE NEXT ONE)**

   Rinse and repeat for loss of levels.

Comment: I can't think of how to word it, but you should add the fact that jailing yourself and having a long sentence reset's skill progression.

Comment: @FinnRayment I didn't think of that! You should definitely add that as an answer.

Comment: Ill edit yours, edit it if you don't like my wording.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any rings or blessings set that make your level up percentage higher, this will be the factor that you should unequip or change.

The only way you won't level up at all is get poisoned or run around in circles pointlessly.

I get not wanting to level up. It takes a lot of fun out of the game.:)